# Application drawer item selection not working

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

I am creating side menu for my app, but some reason menu is not working (commented on position):

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener/*,ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener*/ {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "DTAG";
    public static MySQLiteHelper db;
    private static MyPagerAdapter adapter;
    Preference prefs;
    Context context;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.context = this;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermission();

        } else {
            startApp();
        }
    }


    private void startApp() {


        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        prefs = new Preference(this);


        db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);


        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }


    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            checkNewData();
            reattach();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        Log.d(TAG, "Sel");

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CamSel"); //Not working
            return true;
        }

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/tab_background_color"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator_color"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_selected_text_color"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text_color" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

acvitity_main_drawer:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it wrong its basically `onNavigationItemSelected()` method so how used this is implemented the interface to the activity `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`
and then

```
NavigationView naivigationView  = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

You have got the reference of drawer layout not the navigation view.

And to close the drawer simply do

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked, how can in close the drawer after item selection?

Comment: @Dim please check the updated answer , and do accept the answer and vote up if it helped so that it may helps other happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `onOptionsItemSelected` use `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected`